# Running Gradle tasks on Android Studio (not command line) build using "Execute Before Build" not working as expected

Tags: android-studio, gradle, groovy

In Android Studio (not the command line), how can I trigger a gradle task to run before every build?

I'd like to have 2 Gradle tasks when I click the Run button in Android Studio. Some information:

- When I open the Gradle tool window on the right side of the screen, I can see both of my tasks listed under MyProject > Tasks > other.
- When I right-click on one of the tasks and run it, it is successful.
- PROBLEM: When I right-click on one of the tasks and select "Execute Before Build", looking through the build log, I see no indication that it's been executed. Both generate strings, and the files are nowhere to be found when clicking the Run button at the project level.
- Both tasks work via the command line, when clicking the run button specific to the task in the gradle.build file, and when right-clicking and running via the Gradle tool in the GUI.

How can I make them run when I click the project-level Run button?

They're both relatively simple:

```
// Module-level gradle.build -- I've also tried in the project-level gradle.build
// Import Ant targets and prefix all task names with MyProject-
ant.importBuild("path/to/my/build.xml") { antTargetName ->
    'MyProject-' + antTargetName
}

// Generate string resources when `$ ./gradlew assemble` is run (including ci/cd)
assemble {
    dependsOn 'MyProject-generate-strings'
}
```

I've also tried creating a Run Configuration by following these steps:

1. Run > Edit Configurations > Gradle > Add new run configuration
2. Name: Generate Strings
3. Run: <task_1> <task_2> // I've tried with only one also
4. Apply, OK
5. Right-click the "Generate Strings" Run Configuration and select "Execute Before Build"

However, after clicking the Project-level Run button, I see no indication that either task has run.

Comment: Instead of fighting the way it all works, why don't you just make the run task depend on the other task you want to run?

Comment: @tim_yates Could you post an example as an answer, please?